# How do I reference other FIELD using foreign key in Django?

Tags: python, django

So I'm using Django and have a `foreignkey` field. Let me show you the model first.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

class Content(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()

    source = models.ForeignKey("Book", related_name='book', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    key_line = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null=True)
```

I used `serializer` to load the api to my React front end. But then, the `source` field is displayed as integer, which probably is the `id` of `Book` model.
However what I want to do is load the `title` of each book in the `source` field. 
Any advice?

FYI, other codes.
views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def each_book(request, pk):
    this_book = Content.objects.get(pk=pk)
    serialized = ContentSerializer(this_book, context={'request':request})
    return Response(serialized.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class ContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just pass `book` to the `context` field and call it like:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def each_book(request, pk):
    this_book = Content.objects.get(pk=pk)
    serialized = ContentSerializer(this_book, context={'request':request, 'book': this_book})
    return Response(serialized.data)
```

Then

```
class ContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        book_title = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        class Meta:
            model = Content
            fields = '__all__'
        
        def get_book_title(self, obj): # Note that obj is `content` in this case.
             return self.context['book'].title
```

Make sure you include it in your `fields` too. Not sure if it works with `__all__`. If it doesn't, then just explicitly write all your fields out with the `book_title` field included.

Comment: Thanks. However I had to `return self.context['book'].source.title` in order to do what I intended. :)

Comment: Yup, my error was mistaking your `book` parameter as a `book object `as opposed to a `content object`.